# Is there a reason that "Mobile Browser View" site feature is enabled by default inside Team site while it is disabled inside "Enterprise wiki"

Tags: 2013, administration, mobile, team-sites, enterprise-wiki

I am working on SharePoint enterprise server 2013. and i have created 2 site collections:-

1. Team site
2. Enterprise Wiki

now i want to allow users to access these 2 site collections using mobile views. so i checked if the "Mobile Browser View" site feature is enabled. and i have noted the following :-

1. On Team Site the "Mobile Browser View" is enabled by default.
2. While on the Enterprise Wiki it is disabled by default.

so can anyone adivce if there is a valid reason from MS why the "Mobile Browser View" got enabled by default in Team sites, while it is disabled by default inside Enterprise wikis ??

second question. is enabling and disabling a "Mobile Browser View" on sites have any adv/disa ?  or i can dynamically do this . i am comparing it with Publishing features , where if i enable Publishing features new lists will be created and additional options will be shown, and even if i disabled the Publishing features the lists will stay. so for "Mobile Browser View" is it more safer to enable/disable it compared to Publishing features?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Mobile Browser View` is disabled by default inside `Enterprise wikis` because of

- The wiki page is not rendered properly (blank) on mobile devices
- Rich text editor is not supported on mobile devices.

I also read that

> Mobile access is not supported for Web sites based on legacy WIKI site
>   definitions.

**Ref :** official Microsoft article [Overview of Mobile Pages and the Redirection System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462572%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

So if you need to use Mobile view it's recommended to use the Team site rather than Enterprise wiki site

Comment: so are you saying that the enterprise wiki site collection inside the sharepoint 2013 ,, is based on a legacy wiki site definitions ?? second point my in my case i do not want to use team sites, as the wiki library inside it will be based on Text layout rather than page layout.. and inside the text layout i can not custom it to be showing additional categories beside the built-in  "Wiki Category",, now we are building a wiki for all the departments for our company so i need to have the most flexible and enterprise appraoch which is found inside the Enterprise wiki SC..

Comment: but sure if MS will release a fix for the enterprise wiki site collection limitation on mobile devices

Comment: third point. also the link you provide https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462572%28v=office.14%29.aspx is talking avout SP 2010,, so not sure if this applies to SP 2013 also? as the Enterprise wiki site collection found inside SP 2013 is a new feature in 2013.

Comment: for the third point . check this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj673030.aspx check the Table: Browser-based mobile views on SharePoint site templates : it mentions only the supported template for Mobile view

Comment: for second point , based on my knowledge no fixes for this limitation till now from Microsoft

Comment: for first comment for this purpose why you don't use publishing template rather than wiki site ?!!

Comment: now i did not work on publishing templates before, so i am not sure if they provide the same features as in enterprise wikis site collection? now we choice enterprise wiki site collection because we were planning to build a wiki site which store all the manuals and procedures for our client. and from technical point of view, i found that enterprise wikis site collection provides the following main features which are not provided by wiki library; the ability to modify the wiki page

Comment: by modifying the related enterprisewiki.aspx page layout and add extra wiki category columns. the ability to rate pages. more enterprise way to have an enterprise wiki for the company compared to wiki library.. but recently i came across the mobile view problem on enterprise wiki.. so now it will be hard to switch from enterprise wiki to other templetes such as publishing templates for the current project as it already have 2,000+ wiki pages,, but maybe i will consider this for future projects.. but still not sure what are the main differences between enterprise wiki & publishing template

Comment: can you please check my above comments?

Comment: the main difference is page layout feature ,  based on your comments I suggest to you , create a publishing site ,  create a library ,  add a content type for your document with this Enterprise wiki page  where you will find category and rating , and try if it render also at mobile view or not , I think the issue is related to the type of page not the site template , but if it's rendered properly in the publishing site so go ahead to migrate to publishing feature , if not try to disable mobile view at wiki site and check the site in mobile , may be default size match your requirements

Answer (score 1):

M.Qassas has answered your first question. So, I will answer the second question related to advantages/disadvantages of `mobile browser view feature`.

There is one major disadvantage that I see - In case you have activated publishing features and you are using `Content Editor/Script editor webparts` on a publishing page, then you might have the below error on mobile devices:

*(Some apps, such as Content Editor(script editor), are not supported in mobile view. Tapping on title area can bring up navigation window.)*

So, you will need to turn off(deactivate) the feature, `Mobile browser view` and after that it will render correctly on mobile devices.

Comment: or i can keep it enable ,, and if the user face the error , they can re-direct to the normal view

Comment: what about custom pages or site pages ? If you are using Script editor/content editor webparts on any publishing page or wiki page, then they will face this error there.

Comment: i did not get your point what is the relation between having publishing page + script editor + mobile browser view activated ?? can you explain it in more details if u can.

Comment: I dont have an explanation for this. But this looks to be an issue at the SharePoint product level. Microsoft has purposely (for some reason, unknown to us) disabled script editor/CEWP webparts in mobile view. Looking from my viewpoint as SP developer/consultant, i dont see any relation as to why this should occur. But the people behind SP product may have a different viewpoint about this. Sorry, dont have a better explanation for this. I faced this issue and had to deactivate the feature to resolve it. Hence wrote this as a disadvantage :)